# Rails delayed_job in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

Say you have a mailer with an action in Rails, being called from some model using `delay`, for example:

```
class ReportMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default from: "hello@shopstar.co.za"

  def order_received(order)
    @order = order
    mail(:to => @order.shop.email, :subject  => "You have a new order on Shopstar")
  end
end
```

order.rb:

```
      if self.shop.email_preference.on_order?
       ReportMailer.delay.order_received(self) unless self.source == "pos"
      end
```

Will this send the mail from a development environment?

and

Will this send the mail in the production version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will this send the mail from a development environment?

It will send an email depending on your STMP settings

Rails has settings for `config.action_mailer`, which you can define in both `config/environments/development.rb` & `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
  #config/environments/development.rb
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => "************.co.uk",
      :user_name            => "****@gmail.com",
      :password             => ENV["gmail"],
      :authentication       => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000"}
```

Whichever environment you run `delayed_job` on, you need to be sure these details are set up in your environment config files

Comment: Both production.rb and development.rb have identical stmp settings.

Comment: There is a line that says : `config.consider_all_requests_local       = true` in development.rb.. Can this be a possible influence?

Comment: That will basically say whether to threat requests as development (local) or production when you run the app. So it depends on how your system is set up as to how much influence it could have :)

Answer (score 8):

delayed job workers need to be running,

### For development mode run:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec bin/delayed_job start
```

You may face that error:

```
bash: bin/delayed_job: No such file or directory
```

So you will have to generate the bin/delayed_job file running that command:

```
bundle exec rails generate delayed_job
```

### While in production you should run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
```

Above commands are for **Rails 4**. For **Rails 3**, you should do:

`script/delayed_job` instead of `bin/delayed_job`

Check delayed_jobs page for more [details](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

Answer (score 0):

Will this send the mail from a development environment?
Will this send the mail in the production version?

Its all depends on your environment smtp setting in each file (development.rb,production.rb)

In order to use delayed job in your environment requires running worker to handle this in background. Try look at foreman gem to help you which can run server and worker just using foreman start.

Answer (score 0):

With an unchanged environment configuration then it won't send emails in development and it will send emails in production.

You should see something like this in `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries    = false
```

Which prevents emails from being sent in your development environment. You can find more details on the configuration options for action mailer in the [configuration guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-action-mailer)

Don't forget if you are delaying sending messages then you need your delayed jobs to be processed too.

Answer (score 0):

First let me answer your second question to send mail from your system whether live/development, you need smtp settings. For SMTP settings example you can took a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html .

Secondly, this configuration settings goes in one of the environment files. In which environment file it goes depends on which environment your application is running. If your live server is running in development environment then these changes will be made in `config/environments/development.rb`

Hope that clarifies.